# How can I run the next test case from the [BeforeScenario] hook when the current test fails in between in specflow?

Tags: bdd, specflow

I have a scenario written as below in specflow.

```
@tag
Scenario: Test scenario 1
Step in Gherkin
Step in Gherkin
Step in Gherkin

@tag
Scenario: Test scenario 2
Step in Gherkin
Step in Gherkin
Step in Gherkin

@tag
Scenario: Test scenario 2
Step in Gherkin
Step in Gherkin
Step in Gherkin
```

I also have below hooks for the above feature and scenarios.

```
[BeforeScenario("tag")]
public static void BeforeS()
{
}

[BeforeFeature("tag")]
public static void BeforeF()
{
}

[BeforeTestRun("tag")]
public static void BeforeTR()
{
}

[AfterScenario("tag")]
public static void AfterS()
{
}

[AfterFeature("tag")]
public static void AfterF()
{
}

[AfterTestRun("tag")]
public static void AfterTR()
{
}
```

When I run all the tests together if 1st test case fails, how I do I start the next test all from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Each test scenario is independent and it will execute seperately. It means even if one of your scenarios failed other scenarios will execute fine.